# python - multiprocessing shared values process and loops

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around two things in multiprocessing for python. I have researched the docs but still don't understand:

1. how to start and join the process in a `n-loop` (non-repeated code, don't know if I need to do anything special in a `Process` loop)
2. how to add to results to a list from each respective process.

Purpose: To break down a giant list and run each chunk separately for a faster run-time.

```
queue = Queue()

def filter(aBigList, startV, endV, startP, endPr, minV):

    chunks = list(split(aBigList, 6))

    p1 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[0], startP, endPr))
    p2 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[1], startP, endPr))
    p3 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[2], startP, endPr))
    p4 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[3], startP, endPr))
    p5 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[4], startP, endPr))
    p6 = Process(target=func1, args=(chunks[5], startP, endPr))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()

    #wait for all processes to finish
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
    p6.join()

    print(queue)

def func1(subList, startP, endPr):

    for i in subList:
        price = ind.getPrice(i) #returns a price of argument element
        if startP <= float(price) <= endPr:
            print("added")
            queue.put(i)
```

Comment: Well, your code is correct and should work fine.
Do you see "added" or <Queue.Queue instance ...> output?
You can check if processes are spawning and "split" function does not stuck, for example.

Comment: Ah, yea. You are correct. I didn't see the print! I added a string along with the print and it did end up printing.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a Worker Pool

The python `multiprocessing` standard library provides a [nice class that can be very helpful](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) for this use case: `multiprocessing.Pool`. It will manage a number of workers for you, and you simply send units of work for it to complete as you need. Here is your code, adapted to use a pool instead of manually creating your own processes.

```
PROCESS_COUNT = 6

def filter_list(aBigList, startV, endV, startP, endPr, minV):
    list_chunks = list(chunks(aBigList, PROCESS_COUNT))

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT)

    for chunk in list_chunks:
        pool.apply_async(func1, (chunk, startP, endPr))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    while not queue.empty():
        print(queue.get())
```

Also, the `chunks` function can be simply written as, [borrowed from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/416500)

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `Pool.map()` method and return the values from `func1` instead of using an external Queue object, but both will work.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel here - using Pool is the right thing to do. +1